# Using Bash script to check string length during compilation

Tags: bash, compilation, makefile

I'm trying to check a target name (defined in Makefile) during compilation. For example, if the name of the target name exceeds 10 characters, the compilation process aborts, and throws out an error message "TARGET name exceeds 10 chars".

Part of the code:

```
TARGETNAME:
@if [ ${#TARGET_NAME} -ge 10 ]; then \ 
echo "TARGET name exceeds 10 chars"; \
exit; \
fi
```

Then when I try to compile, `make TARGETNAME`, I got an error message:

```
/bin/sh: line 0: [: -ge: unary operator expected
```

I'm not sure if this Makefile is written in Bash or an other language. The syntax looks like it is in Bash script, but I see no command like `SHELL := /bin/bash` in the code.

**thanks all for the help, problem solved**

Comment: 1. Leave space after 10. 2. replace ercho with echo.

Comment: @SMA I made typos in this post, but in the code it is exactly as you said.

Comment: what is @ doing before if? Can you post actual script (or part of it if its huge)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Im completely new to makefile with bash script.  I use that to get the length of the TARGETNAME, and compares it with 10.

Comment: @M.S That's not Bash. That's valid Bourne shell, or equivalent. The error even says `/bin/sh`. The `@` is a make thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
TARGETNAME:
    t=$@ && [ $${#t} -lt 10 ] || { echo "Target name $$t has 10 or more chars"; false; }
```

---

Edit. It seems you don't really grok the thing. Please do the following little experiment: in an empty directory, create a file called `Makefile` with the following content:

```
short:
    t=$@ && [ $${#t} -lt 10 ] || { echo "Target name $$t has 10 or more chars"; false; }

longtargetname:
    t=$@ && [ $${#t} -lt 10 ] || { echo "Target name $$t has 10 or more chars"; false; }
```

Then, from within this directory:

```
$ make short
t=short && [ ${#t} -lt 10 ] || { echo "Target name $t has 10 or more chars"; false; }
$ make longtargetname 
t=longtargetname && [ ${#t} -lt 10 ] || { echo "Target name $t has 10 or more chars"; false; }
Target name longtargetname has 10 or more chars
make: *** [longtargetname] Error 1
```

See? the line is printed before being executed (that's `make`'s default). You can disable printing by prepending `@` to the line.

In GNU `make`, if you want something more polished, you can define a function:

```
define check_length
    @t=$@; \
    if [ $${#t} -ge 10 ]; then \
        echo "Target name $$t has 10 or more chars"; \
        false; \
    fi
endef

short:
    $(call check_length,$@)

longtargetname:
    $(call check_length,$@)
```

Comment: This line prints will be printed out instead of executed. This Makefile might not be a Bash script, I'm adding more code in.

Comment: @M.S: did you try it? just put the lines I wrote in an empty Makefile and run `make` or `make TARGETNAME`. The key point here is to transfer the Makefile variable to the shell, using `t=$@`. You can also replace the target name `TARGETNAME` with the template `%`.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote! if you think this answer is wrong or not useful, please leave a comment… maybe I can improve it (and maybe I'll learn something in the process).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have tried your code. It just get printed out, not excuted. Is this means that this Makefile is written in a different language? BTW I didn't down vote your answer.

Comment: @M.S What do you mean by _It just get printed out, not executed?_ It _is_ executed! you'll see it printed on your terminal output, because that's `make`'s default. Prepend the line with `@` to disable printing: `@t=$@ && [ $${#t} -lt 10 ]`... This code is written in make's language.

Comment: Thanks! your code indeed works. But my case is slightly different, the target_name is predefined in another file, not passed in from command line. Do you know how to change the code to make it work?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have made it work by modified slightly. 
`@t=$(JOB_NAME) && [ $${#t} -lt 20 ] || { echo "JOB_NAME $$t has 20 or more chars"; false; }`

Comment: Do you have any reference about this make language; i can not completely understand its syntax. Thanks

Comment: @M.S: There's the [GNU `make` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)...

Answer (score 1):

`${#TARGET_NAME}` is a reference to a *Makefile variable* with the (probably invalid) name `#TARGET_NAME`. If this is undefined (as it would be unless you found a way to create crazy Makefile variable names) the statement that is evaluated in the shell context is `if [  -ge 10 ]; then`, which results in the error you see. You need to use `if [ $${#TARGET_NAME} -ge 10 ]; then` which will result in `${#TARGET_NAME}` being treated in a shell context..

Comment: `if [ $${#TARGET_NAME} -ge 10 ]`, fixed the error message, but the compilation continues no matter what condition I put in the if statement.

Comment: Then it seems there's a different issue, and you should post another question with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get to the bottom of it as quickly as possible.